# What are System Requirements for Magento 2.4?

Tags: server-setup, setup, magento2.4

I am using ubuntu 18.04 with PHP 7.3 and MySQL 5.7 Magento 2.3.5 is working fine what are requirements for Magento 2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento 2.4 is just released on July 28, 2020

Here are the Main Points I have extracted from [Magento DevDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html)

**Operating System**

Magento 2.4 on only work on Linux distributions Like

- Linux (RHEL)
- CentOS
- Ubuntu
- Debian

Magento 2.4 is not supported on

- Windows OS
- Mac OS

**Apache**

- Magento 2.4 will work on Apache 2.4

**PHP**

- Magento 2.4 will work on PHP 7.3 and 7.4
- It is recommended to use PHP 7.2 for testing
- PHP 7.4.2 has some bugs which cause some messages to not render properly

**MYSQL**

- Magento 2.4 will work on MySQL 8.0

You can read Full Requirements [Here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html)

Answer (score 0):

Magento will run anywhere with `LEMP/LAMP` stack.

but add `2Gb` or `4Gb` `RAM` for `ELK` stack extra memory.

or use `AWS ELK` remote service

Answer (score 0):

On the screenshot You can see which version was required for Magento2.4
[image]