# Magento 2.3.2 Upgrade to 2.4

Tags: upgrade

I need to upgrade my magento 2.3.2, can i upgrade it directly to latest version 2.4 or should i upgrade first to 2.3.3 then to 2.3.4 then to 2.3.5 and then 2.4 ?

Thank you

Comment: What is that possible risk you want to avoid or just simply test the best fit version?

Answer (score 0):

First take to older version website backup and after your run direct `magento 2.4.0` version.

**`Magento Open Source:`**

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.0 --no-update
```

**`Magento Commerce:`**

```
composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition=2.4.0 --no-update
```

And you want to read more information check this :-

**https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html**

**`THANKS.`**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Upgrade you have to upgrade your server [See Here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/318514/what-are-system-requirements-for-magento-2-4/318515#318515)